# Is there such as things as HTML Template API?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, templates

Is there such a thing as a HTML template API I can use in a rails application? I'm currently creating a blog project application and would like users to use already customised html templates. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Why not use the html template rails uses - erb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have several stylesheets and have your user pick one. In your layouts/application.html.erb, make your stylesheet attribute a variable populate it with the template (read stylesheet) as selected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something where users can supply their own templates without giving them full privileges to execute arbitrary ruby code then you might like to take a look at [liquid markup](http://liquidmarkup.org/).